# Hartshorne's proof of the exact sequence $\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Cl} X \to \operatorname{Cl} U \to 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, Proposition II.6.5 reads (in part):

> Let $X$ satisfy (*), let $Z$ be a proper closed subset of $X$, and let $U = X \setminus Z$.  Then:
>
> [...]
>
> (c) if $Z$ is an irreducible subset of codimension 1, then there is an exact sequence
>
> $$\mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Cl} X \to \operatorname{Cl} U \to 0,$$
>
> where the first map is defined by $1 \mapsto 1 \cdot Z$.

The condition (*) here is just saying that $X$ has a workable theory of Weil divisors, viz.

> (*) $X$ is a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one.

Here's is Hartshorne's proof:

> The kernel of $\operatorname{Cl} X \to \operatorname{Cl} U$ consists of divisors whose support is contained in $Z$.  If $Z$ is irreducible, the kernel is just the subgroup of $\operatorname{Cl} X$ generated by $1 \cdot Z$.

As written, this doesn't seem to make sense.  For instance, consider the case where $X = \mathbb{P}^2$, $Z = V(x_0) \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, and hence $U = X \setminus Z \cong \mathbb{A}^1$.  Then $\operatorname{Cl} U = 0$, so this says that *every* divisor in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is supported on $Z$.  But of course this is false, because there are higher degree curves.

Of course, these higher-degree curves are *linearly equivalent* to divisors supported on $Z$, or the theorem would be false.  But I don't see how this has been proven.

Comment: Probably he's thinking about $0 \to \mathbb Z \to \operatorname{Div} X \to \operatorname{Div} U \to 0$ and then taking the quotients, possibly losing exactness on the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's not quite correct as written, but the argument is straightforward—or, at least, as straightforward as other things omitted in the book.

Given a Weil divisor $D$ on $X$, if $D$ maps to zero in $\operatorname{Cl} U$, then there is a rational function $f$ on $U$ with $(f) = D\cap U$ on $U$.  Then, on $X$, $D-(f)$ is supported on $Z$, so $D$ is linearly equivalent to a divisor supported on $Z$.

Comment: I thought of something like that, but it wasn't clear to me that on an abstract integral scheme every regular function on an open set lifts to an element of $K(X)$.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury For an integral scheme, $K(X)$ is defined to be the set of functions on nonempty open subsets of $X$, up to equivalence.

Comment: How do you know that the rational function $f$ is regular ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I'm not sure I understand the question.  It's regular on $U$ by assumption, hence an element of $K(X)$.  That it yields an honest Weil divisor on $X$ follows from regularity in codimension 1, but this is folded into the assumptions.

Comment: There is no assumption that $f$ is regular: linear equivalence of Weil divisors is defined by means of rational functions, not regular ones. Here you claim that a rational function whose associated Weil divisor is zero must be regular. This is not clear to me under the hypothesis $(*)$ unless  $U$ is also assumed normal.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg You are right; I unconsciously assumed that $D$ was effective on $U$.  Am I correct that the proof is correct once "regular" is replaced by "rational"?

Comment: Your proof is now absolutely correct :+1.